# What to do when there is no answer for a bountied question?

Tags: discussion

Recently I put a bounty on this question at max bounty:

[How can I remove items from the allowed values list of a select field that has data for the values?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112315/how-can-i-remove-items-from-the-allowed-values-list-of-a-select-field-that-has-d)

There seems to be a consensus as to a general direction to take (use VBO) but no answer I was hoping for. I was going to let the community decide by voting up what it felt was the best answer, but after a decent amount of exposure, no one has voted on anything, so it doesn't seem the community believes in one over the another.

What would be protocol here? Do I just choose one? For the answers that suggest VBO, who would the credit go to, perhaps the person who answered first? Ultimately, however, the question really doesn't have an answer yet.

Comment: This answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/118129/2800, is almost perfect as it happens - you just need to decide whether you want to db_delete or db_update and perhaps set an empty value for the removed fields instead, and chuck a cache clear at the end. If you test that I'm confident you'll be awarding the bounty to that one anyway so this will become moot...

Answer (score 5):

> What would be protocol here? Do I just choose one?

It's totally up to you - if you feel that one of the answers has helped you to reach whatever conclusion you needed to, and is thus worthy of a bounty, go ahead and award it to that one.

If there's no such answer, just don't award the bounty. There's no obligation to award these points to anyone, they're already 'spent' as far as your rep is concerned (you're paying for the exposure, not to get an answer as such).

If the question doesn't have what you would consider a proper/complete answer, then I would suggest not awarding the bounty to anyone (it will send mixed signals to future visitors about your problem having been solved).

Personally I wouldn't recommend basing your decision on arbitrary things like the order in which questions were answered - try to focus more on the quality and specifics of the answer if at all possible.

Comment: Yep, users are paying with reputation for the question's exposure, not for getting an answer. This is not sufficiently stressed as it should, and it is something most users don't understand. There is no need to give the bounty; the important is being honest and give it when an answer really helped, not because reputation has been already lost for the user who offers the bounty.